# Flask: not seeing .env outside of root directory

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

As per [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/), `FLASK_ENV` environmental variable determines whether flask runs in development or production mode.

Hence I have a `.env` file like so:

```
FLASK_ENV="development"
```

and my `app.py` looks like this:

```
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())    
app = Flask(__name__)
config = DevConfig() if os.environ.get('FLASK_ENV') == 'development' else ProdConfig()
app.config.from_object(config)
```

Now here's the problem: if I move `.env` into another folder (in my case `config`), flask stops seeing it. More specifically (and weirdly):

- The env variable is set ok (I can print it from different parts of the app)
- The config loads ok (dev config loads indeed)
- But flask app itself says:

```
Loading .env environment variables…
 * Serving Flask app "app.py"
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

How is it possible that env variable is set, but flask still thinks it's running in prod? Again this only happens when I move `.env` away from the root folder.